# Failed to select data with where clause in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array $DeptID :`array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "8" [2]=> string(2) "11" [3]=> string(2) "15" [4]=> string(2) "17" }` 
Then, I want to select from MySQL database to get data where DeptID in array. My query:

```
$DeptdID = implode(',', $DeptID);
$this->db->select(*)
->from('tabel_data')
->where('DeptID IN ('.$DeptID.')')
->group_by('DeptID', 'ASC')
->get(''):
```

But an error occur.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near (Array) GROUP BY `DeptID` at line 6.
```

Maybe someone can give me a solution

Comment: Did you mean order_by instead of group_by?

Comment: Oh yeah. Sory, actually, my query is so long, but I cut it so people read it simply

Comment: Looks like you either misspelled or are referencing the wrong variable in your `where` clause. Try referencing `$DeptdID` in your `where()` or change `$DeptdID` to `$DeptID` in your first line.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using CodeIgniter you can try using the `where_in` function instead of `implode` and `where`. The `where_in` method will do this for you.

```
$this->db->select(*)
->from('tabel_data')
->where_in('DeptID', $DeptID)
->group_by('DeptID', 'ASC')
->get(''):
```

Comment: No problem. Lots of usefull stuff about active record can be found [here for version <= 2.2](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) and [here for version 3+](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$DeptID` is an array which when cast as a string comes out as `Array`. You need to implode it:

```
$DeptID = '(' . implode(',', $DeptID) . ')';
```

before putting it in the query.

Comment: Yeah, but it still not working. I will update my question

Comment: The `implode` function is kinda critical for getting this to work. (`$DeptdID` != `$DeptID`)